# Convert NSString value to int

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

That may sound odd.

I got an NSString value `NSString * numb = [self.dataDict valueForKey:@"id"];` and i know, that is it some kind of integer (for example, i need that integer to comparison - if val less or equal then something). I need to know what integer is it.

What i've tried:

```
   NSNumber *numba = [self.dataDict valueForKey:@"id"];
```

NSLog output - `numba is 2038735264`

And actually that was 428.

is there any way to achieve the point? Thanks!

That is piece of responseObject:

(
        {
        id = 3;
        dog = "\U041a\U0430\U043a\U043e\U0439-\U0442\U043e \U043c\U0443\U0434\U0430\U043a \U043d\U0430\U043a\U0440\U0443\U0442\U0438\U043b";
        image = "cute_dog/116.jpg";
        score = 586;
    },
        {
        id = 115;
        dog = "\U0422\U0430\U043d\U044f \U041a\U043b\U044e\U043a\U0432\U0438\U043d\U0430";
        image = "cute_dog/115.jpg";
        score = 481;
    },

Comment: Can you post the console output of the whole dictionary object?

Comment: Are you sure the value at "id" is an NSNumber?

Comment: You used `%d` for the format in `NSLog`, right?

Comment: Yes value of id is number, it come from JSON array.

Comment: Code updated. Please take a look

Comment: And are you parsing it properly?

Comment: Yes i got a correct NSMutableArray obj

Comment: And if you log out [self.dataDict valueForKey:@"id"] (without assigning it) what does it say?

Comment: Integer values from 1 to 9999, it correspond with id of elements on web page

Comment: Does it say the type of object in the output? Is it saying the object is an NSNumber?

Comment: @Aggressor it say nothing, its just an array of string. And "id" is a string that contains only number, but apparently is a string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of methods you can use to convert an `NSString` to a number. What numeric type would you like?

```
NSString *string = self.dataDict[@"id"];
int intValue = string.intValue;
NSInteger integerValue = string.integerValue;
long long longLongValue = string.longLongValue;
```

Comment: Best answer, i'l definitely need to remember that.

Answer (score 1):

Trying something like this.

```
NSNumber *numba = [NSNumber numberWithInt[self.dataDict valueForKey:@"id"]];
//For string
NSString *stringValue = [numba stringValue];
//For integer
NSInteger integer = [numba integerValue];
```

Comment: I was just providing options. One `NSString` and one `NSInteger`

Comment: Thank for help kylecman, but it still display values like 2048698912

Comment: I thought I did one step...`NSNumber` to `NSString` and `NSNumber` to `NSInteger`.

Comment: @kylecman Sorry. I read your answer incorrectly. Ignore everything I said earlier.